# jQuery Ajax passing key/value success retrieval to template

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

I can not make this work. All I want is to pass num counter value to template.

```
var ReloadGrid = (function() {
    $.getJSON("/HeaderMenu/GetHeaderGrid", function(data) {
        data.num = $('#mytemp tr').length + 1; // Not working
        $("#gridTemplate").tmpl(data).appendTo("#mytemp");
    });
 });
```

Template:

```
<script id="gridTemplate" type="text/x-jquery-tmpl">
    <tr class="gridRow">
        <td class="numberingTd">
            ${num}          
        </td>
        <td class="cellTd">
            <input id="index" name="index" class="numberField" type="text" value="${IndexOrder}" />
        </td>
        <td class="cellTd">${DisplayName}</td>
        <td class="cellTd ">${UrlName} Us</td>
    </tr>
</script>
```

And also how can I add numbers in template like `${num} + 1`?

Answer (score 0):

Use the javascript console (or equivalent in whatever browser you have) to get a meaningful error

Have you tried simply `alert($('#mytemp tr').length)` to see if the value can be found?

Comment: returning value 1. I am using firefox debugger. I don't see 1 on the other side as well.

Comment: I have edited my question and added grid template to show you.